# Why does mvim clear highlight groups on startup?

Tags: vim, macvim

I recently started using [vim-makegreen](https://github.com/reinh/vim-makegreen) with mvim.

The issue is that the red/green bars do not work with mvim.  They do work with mvim -v (or otherwise console vim).

After further investigation it appears that the highlight groups that are defined as:

```
hi GreenBar term=reverse ctermfg=white ctermbg=green guifg=white guibg=green
hi RedBar   term=reverse ctermfg=white ctermbg=red guifg=white guibg=red
```

within makegreen.vim are cleared by mvim just prior to calling the .gvimrc file.  After mvim has started I get:

```
:hi RedBar
RedBar         xxx cleared    

:hi GreenBar
GreenBar         xxx cleared
```

Does anyone have any insights into why mvim is clobbering highlight groups?  The only work around that I have found thus far is to redefine them again inside .gvimrc.  But this is clearly a pain.  Trying to figure out if I am missing something here.

### Update

I just stripped down my .vimrc and using pathogen I only place makegreen in bundle dir.  The result is the same behavior.

My .vimrc has only one line:

```
call pathogen#infect()
```

The bundle directory only contains makegreen bundle. The autoload directory only has the pathogen.vim.  I removed .gvimrc.

I then start mvim and execute `:hi RedBar` and get the same result as above.  I used an echo statement to confirm that makegreen.vim is being sourced.

I installed mvim with `brew install macvim`.  The version of macvim is 7.3(64) and I am on OSX Lion.

### Update 2

I just took it a step further and removed the reliance on pathogen.  Now I only have makegreen.vim in plugin directory and an empty .vimrc file.  Same result.

Comment: Works for me until I source my .vimrc again. Can we see your colorscheme and/or vimrc?

Comment: see update above for simple configuration

Comment: I have set none.  The updates above are literally run with no vimrc nor gvimrc.  I am starting to think that the cocoa implementation for macvim somehow does some type of a clear before sourcing the gvimrc file.  I tracked it right to that point when the clear occurs.

Comment: Try :e $VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim and look at line 14

Comment: Ahh.  Yes.  So what is the standard way for a plugin to set a color scheme when using mvim?  It appears that all of the plugins are loaded and then `hi clear` gets called wiping them out.  Should the plugin have used colors directory or something else?

Comment: I'm actually not sure - I didn't really look at this too carefully. Try calling a colorscheme in your vimrc. e.g. `colorscheme default`. Might have something to do with startup order, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add `let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1` to your `~/.vimrc`. See the comment before the colorscheme is loaded in your global `gvimrc`:

```
" Load the MacVim color scheme.  This can be disabled by loading another color
" scheme with the :colorscheme command, or by adding the line
"   let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1
" to ~/.vimrc.
if !exists("macvim_skip_colorscheme") && !exists("colors_name")
    colorscheme macvim
endif
```

All color schemes clear the highlights.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The workaround was to redefine GreenBar and RedBar in `~/.vimrc` (or `python.vim`, etc.)